# Highcharts: Reveal part of bar graph on click

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a simple column graph in highcharts with two data series. I want to accomplish the following two things:

1. First, show only the first pair of columns (Case 1).
2. Then, when the user clicks anywhere, reveal all the remaining columns (Cases 2 and 3).

How can that be done?

```
$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
       chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Case 1', 'Case 2', 'Case 3'],
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Type A',
            data: [ 10, 20, 30 ]
        }, {
            name: 'Type B',
            data: [ 15, 20, 25 ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: [You can add a series if you like](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-addseries/) and trigger it with a .on('click') if you're using jquery

Comment: Is it also possible to add parts of a series, or, alternatively, modify the values of a series on click?

Comment: You should post these as separate questions, or part of the question above, so that it helps people when they're searching for solutions, but to answer your question, yes: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.setData

Comment: I'm going to use your suggested `setData()` function as a workaround for my original question. I'd still like to know whether there is an elegant way of revealing part of a bar graph without modifying the data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the workaround I'm going to use:

1. first set the data to 0
2. insert a button; when pressed, modify the data

For this, add a button in the HTML part:

```
<button id="button" class="autocompare">Reveal whole graph</button>
```

... and add a button handler in the JS part:

```
$(function () {
     $('#container').highcharts({
         chart: {
             type: 'column'
         },
         xAxis: {
             categories: ['Case 1', 'Case 2', 'Case 3']
         },
         series: [{
             name: 'Type A',
             data: [10, 0, 0]
         }, {
             name: 'Type B',
             data: [15, 0, 0]
         }]
     });

     // Button handler
     $('#button').click(function () {
         var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
         chart.series[0].setData([10, 20, 30]);
         chart.series[1].setData([15, 20, 25]);
         this.disabled = true;
     });

 });
```

If there a better answer without modifying the data, please let me know.

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution. There's no option like "hide point" (at least not for the column). You can also use different solution: [xAxis.setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes). Just first show first category only, then all of them, without modifying the data. Of course, graph will look different when comparing to your solution.

Comment: OK, thank @PawełFus and Duniyadnd. Then I'm going to use this solution. Look like I will accept my answer as solution, although it was Duniyadnd's idea. Is there a way to give him/her a reward?

Comment: Nicely done, and thank you for the gesture for trying to give me the points, it's not necessary - only one slight suggestion is that you can just hide your button after the process: $(this).hide();